# Is there a point to uploading a feature graphic in the current Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

The Google Play store used to display a large banner on app pages, known as the *feature graphic*, but the new layout no longer displays this.

Is there a chance it will come back at some point or is the feature graphic image used in a different setting? Or is there simply no reason to create one anymore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are still at least 3 good reasons to create a feature graphic:

1) Features

The "Editors' Choice" area of the Play Store app uses feature graphics:
[image: Android Play Store Editors' Choice activity]

2) Play Store widget

The Play Store widget uses feature graphics for any users that place the widget on their home screen. I've used this widget a lot, and trust me it's not just angry birds on there. Many of the apps I've seen have only ~1000 downloads, and earned placement on my widget because I had other apps from the same developer. So even if you have a low-budget app, it's still worth it to have a feature graphic for this free promotion.
[image: Play Store Widget]

3) It is required to make changes to the play store listing after August 31st, 2014. 
[image]

Comment: Do these use the "Feature Graphic" or "Promo Graphic"?

Comment: Both Google Play and the Play Store Widget use the "Feature Graphic" as of December 2, 2013. The "Promo Graphic" is used by the Android Market app that still exists for older devices (pre v2.2/Froyo).

Comment: is there a change this will come back on the site like the older version ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a feature graphic image because the  you will have to show the graphic feature image if you get your app gets featured then it is must....

Comment: I didn't see it... where is that?

Comment: No one should be downvoting this, he's right.  The marketing team will skip over your app if your store listing assets aren't up to date.  Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en